# Continuous Integration for Xcode projects using jenkins. I can't see any setting for the configure page after installing the Xcode plugin?

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I've installed the Xcode plugin and restarted Jenkins, and it's reporting that the plugin is installed. However when I go to the configure page there is no difference, yet the XCode plugin wiki page https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin  has a screenshot showing over a dozen different fields that should be added to the configuration panel.   Why can't I see any setting for the configure page after installing the Xcode plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the proper build step under the Build section of your job.

[image]